Is it possible to set properties on a scene in a TileMap/TileSet?
If I have the following:
sample of code showing exported properties:
[Export]
public TileSet TileSet { get; set; }

[Export]
public string TileName { get; set; }

Godot properties panel demonstrating the previous image working:

And my TileSet has the scene added to a scene collection:

Is there any way to provide values for these two properties when the scene is added as part of a TileSet?

What have you tried so far that didn't work?

In the screenshots I've included, I can't find anywhere to put a value.

Sorry, specifically in the tilemap editor... :)

So to clarify, you have a Tile scene with TileSet and TileName properties and you're putting it in a TileSet's scene collection.
And you want to update these variables automatically to the tileset and tile name it has when placed in the tilemap?

Yeah, I guess the best way to put it would be that when I add the scene to the tileset, I'd like to also be able to hard-wire values for the properties as part of that assignment.
So for example, maybe I could add the same scene multiple times, but each time with a different parameter.  Stuff like 0 with red, 1 with green, 2 with blue (not my actual use case, but just an example), etc etc...

For future reference, please use formatted text for code rather than screenshots.

According to the Github issue status, it is not currently possible. The issue might be solved in the future though, most likely by adding a scene painter tool, which would allow painting scenes just like tiles, aligning them to a Tilemap grid.
Right now, as a workaround, you can use Godot-Instance-Dock plugin, that basically works like the scene painter tool I described, minus the feature of copying grid from a Tilemap (you'll have to set it up manually to match the Tilemap).
